# passing selected item value to new view controller swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I created this collection view controller to show the number of levels in the game
I want to know what level user selected
so i want to pass selected item number to gameviewcontroller

this is my code in collection view controller right now

```
verride func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let path = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    let gamevc = GameViewController
    gamevc = segue.destinationViewController
}
```

this seems to be not working, how do i pass which items number was selected to gameviewcontroller?

Comment: This is not working because you are not doing anything with `path` or `gamevc`.

Comment: Typically you would have an instance variable in `GameViewController` that you would access by doing `gamevc.someInstanceVariable` after the line `let gamevc = GameViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Add  `var paths = [AnyObject]()` as an instance variable to `GameViewController`, and then add `gamevc.paths = path` after `let gamevc = GameViewController`

Comment: edited to `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let path = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
 let gamevc = GameViewController()
 gamevc.paths = path!
 gamevc = segue.destinationViewController  (Error: cannot assign to let value gamevc)
}` and in GameViewController i added 'var paths = [AnyObjest]()`
as you can see im getting an error on that line **(Error: cannot assign to let value gamevc)
}**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this worked

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
let path = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
let gamevc = GameViewController()
gamevc.paths = path!
gamevc = segue.destinationViewController as GameViewController
```

right now i have a lable in my Gameviewcontroller
and one image with indexpath.row number on it..
How do i make cells clickable and when i click it should take me to GameViewController and change gamevc's lable.text to indexpath.row's number?

Comment: Do you mean that your current view controller (i.e. the one before GameViewController) is a UITableViewController? I'm assuming that's why you said, "How do i make cells clickable." If it is a table view controller, you can override UITableView delegate's tableview(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) or tableview(willSelectRowAtIndexPath:) methods to get the selected indexpath.row which you can then store in an instance variable and grab in your prepareForSegue.

Comment: I replaced this code to this in my collectionvc.swift file http://i.imgur.com/56XL2o3.png , this seems to be working , when i click it takes me to GameVC and prints which item was clicked. So now i want to change the label of GameVC to what item number was selected. this is my GameVC http://i.imgur.com/CnPGu3y.png I'm actually new to swift so not sure what code to add to actually change the label.text to seleted indexpath.row

Comment: The easiest thing to do is add `var itemNumber: String! = ""` as an instance variable (i.e. on the class level) to GameViewController and then access that variable in collectionView(didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) in the view controller before GamerViewController (i.e. the method in the first image you just posted). So, after you declare the `gameview` variable in that function, add `gameview.itemNumber = "\(indexPath.row)`. In `viewDidLoad()` in GameViewController, you can set the text of the label to the value of itemNumber by calling `levelLable.text = itemNumber`

Comment: Collection VC http://i.imgur.com/DSBOKGl.png and GameVC http://i.imgur.com/0OcPUry.png , label is showing no value total blank

Comment: You have to add `gameview.itemNum` BEFORE you present the view controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, add where? i've added gameview.itemNum = indexpath.row in didselect func

Comment: Move `gameview.itemNum = "\(indexPath.row)"` before `self.presentViewController(gameview, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Great! Feel free to +1 my comments if they were valuable to you!

Comment: hey trevorj, this is so weird when i double click anywhere on GameVC it takes me back to CollectionVC

Comment: Double click? Meaning double tap? That's really weird. Check to make sure you don't have any mysterious tap gesture recognizers in your code. Also check your interface builder to make sure you didn't accidentally drag any gesture recognizers to your view. That's all I can think of. Good luck!

Comment: i asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633783/double-tap-takes-me-back-to-last-viewcontroller
lets see if anyone answers